# SQL How to check if 2 columns from one table matches a conditional within second table

Tags: sql

Distances Table:

| StartTeam | DestinationTeam | Distances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta Hawks | Boston Celtics | 1234 |
| Brooklyn Nets | Atlanta Hawks | 212 |

Stadiums Table:

| TeamName | Enabled |
| --- | --- |
| Atlanta Hawks | 1 |
| Boston Celtics | 0 |
| Brooklyn Nets | 1 |

I need a sql query that will check if the StartTeam and DestinationTeam are both Enabled within the Stadiums table.

I tried this query to check if both teams are within the Stadiums table but it's clearly not correct. Would love some help!

```
SELECT *
FROM Distances d
LEFT JOIN Stadiums s
ON d.StartTeam = s.[Team Name]
WHERE s.Enabled AND (
    SELECT *
    FROM Distances d
    LEFT JOIN Stadiums s
    ON d.DestinationTeam = s.[Team Name]
    WHERE s.Enabled = 1
)
ORDER BY d.DestinationTeam ASC
```

So the working query would spit out the second row since both Brooklyn Nets and Atlanta Hawks are enabled. The first row wouldn't be returned since Boston Celtics is not enabled.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

| StartTeam | DestinationTeam | Distances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brooklyn Nets | Atlanta Hawks | 212 |

Comment: Adding `desired output` and `DBMS` would help!

Comment: The desired output is the last paragraph but I made it a bit more clear!

Comment: No need for left joins here.

Comment: I cleared up the tables a bit but I think I do need a left join as I will be needing other columns that I didn't include in the question. Just struggling on the main portion of checking both columns to see if theyre enabled in the Stadiums table.

Comment: Join may want a join. But you can clearly use inner joins for this. Your subquery didn't work because it's not correlated. And add `exists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join `Distances` to `Stadiums` *twice*:

```sql
SELECT d.*
FROM Distances d
INNER JOIN Stadiums s1 ON s1.TeamName = d.StartTeam
INNER JOIN Stadiums s2 ON s2.TeamName = d.DestinationTeam
WHERE s1.Enabled + s2.Enabled = 2;
```

Note that the criterion in the `WHERE` clause is asserting that both the start and destination teams are enabled.

Comment: Ahh this is pretty clever. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Distances
where 1 = (
    select min(Enabled) from Stadiums
    where Teamname in (StartTeam, DestinationTeam)
)
```

To get additional columns and stick with your original line of thought:

```
SELECT * FROM Distances d
    INNER JOIN Stadiums s ON d.StartTeam = s.[Team Name]
WHERE s.Enabled = 1 AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Stadiums s2
    WHERE s2.[Team Name] = d.DestinationTeam
      AND s2.Enabled = 1
)
ORDER BY d.DestinationTeam ASC
```

Of course you'll only have access to start team columns in the output that way.

Comment: This looks promising, but the OP is very likely using SQL Server, and I don't know if this syntax will work there.

Comment: It'll work. SQL Server is my usual platform. Might have to cast a bit type to int though.